# E/com.facebook.appevents.RestrictiveDataManager: updateRulesFromSetting failed

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk, android-9.0-pie

When I launch my app from Android Studio, with Facebook SDK installed on my device, Xiaomi Mi A2, it triggers the same error trhee times. It does not stop the app, but I don't know if I am missing something or simply, it is not important, but in the end, it is an error and I want to clarify it.

I am using Android Studio 3.4.1, Android 9 on the Xiaomi A2 and the new clause in build.gradle file is `implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:5.1.0'`. Error has not appeared before upgrading Facebook SDK.

This is what appears in Logcat:

> 2019-06-24 18:24:31.202 25105-25136/com.myapp
>   E/com.facebook.appevents.RestrictiveDataManager:
>   updateRulesFromSetting failed
>       org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of 
>           at org.json.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:449)
>           at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:97)
>           at org.json.JSONArray.(JSONArray.java:92)
>           at org.json.JSONArray.(JSONArray.java:108)
>           at com.facebook.appevents.RestrictiveDataManager.updateFromSetting(RestrictiveDataManager.java:32)
>           at com.facebook.internal.FetchedAppSettingsManager.parseAppSettingsFromJSON(FetchedAppSettingsManager.java:323)
>           at com.facebook.internal.FetchedAppSettingsManager.access$000(FetchedAppSettingsManager.java:63)
>           at com.facebook.internal.FetchedAppSettingsManager$1.run(FetchedAppSettingsManager.java:181)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)

Comment: I am just facing the same problem, your sample was working correctly on the old facebook sdk version ??

Comment: Old for me was 4.40 and there was no error like this, all worked correctly, but this error bother a little

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**EDIT**
The issue has been fixed in version 5.1.1.

---

Revert to 5.0.3 to get rid of this.
5.1.0 is actually *crashing* in production at this method (there's a [bug report here](https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/348297015851098/)). GitHub commits of this file show its rather flawed, the method is called from multiple threads concluding to a concurrency crash because it's using a static ArrayList.

Lately the core FB SDK is kinda bloated with useless stuff and low-quality code. The codeless stuff "feature" that simply can't even be turned off is especially a horror to look at. If you don't strictly need the FB SDK in your app, I'd avoid it until they get their shit figured out.

Comment: The same happens to me even in 5.0.3

Comment: Standing ovation for this comment :D